# How to show <ul> to right and left direction

Tags: php, html, css

I have following table for Menu:

[image]

Query For Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sub_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menu` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `menu` (`id`, `sub_id`, `menu`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Right'),
(2, 0, 'Left'),
(3, 1, 'A1'),
(4, 2, 'B1'),
(5, 3, 'AA1'),
(6, 4, 'BB1');
```

Now I want the result as show the item under right menu to right side of page and left menu to left side from middle of page like this:
[image]

I have tried to do following things:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','rnt_reports');
if( !empty($conn->connect_errno)) die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
echo"Vikas";
menu(0);

function menu($id){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "select * from menu where sub_id ='".$id."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){

             $i = 0;
             if ($i == 0) echo '<ul>';
             echo '<li>' . $row->menu;
             menu($row->id);
             echo '</li>';
             $i++;
             if ($i > 0) echo '</ul>';

        }

}
```

Result :

Vikas

```
Right
    A1
        AA1

Left
    B1
        BB1
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a database to print your menu ? It's unneeded and probably slow and not recommended.

Comment: What do you want, please specify more. And the database table looks a bit weird. Why not have separate tables or set them as a ultype left/right 0/1 or something. Please be more specific

Comment: Ignoring the words Left and Right I think it's pretty clear he wants to create a chain from sub_id to id. If no one's solved this by the time I get back to my desk I should be able to help. ;)

Comment: Yes I want a chain as told @ DanielM

Answer (score 0):

Try organising it with an object like this

```
class MenuItem {
    public $id;
    public $menu;
    public $subId;
    public $subMenu = [];

    public function applySubMenus(array $allItems)
    {
        foreach($allItems as $key => $item) {
            if($item->subId == $this->id) {
                $this->subMenu[] = $item;
                unset($allItems[$key]); // This should prevent infinite recursion
                $item->applySubMenus($allItems);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Admittedly, I haven't tested this, but it should work. You'll need to load data from the records into this object first.

**Update:** Code fixed and tested: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4007b46b33cc9803c676a89065b6c0ff7d4b252c